# Simple Vector art rejected by Shutterstock because of Bitmapping

Tags: vector, line-art, graphic-styles, art

I submitted few simple vector art to ShutterStock but most of them were rejected due to this:

> Linked Images / Bitmaps / Raster Effects: Vectors containing linked
>   images, bitmaps, and/or raster effects are not acceptable.

I followed their tips to remove the raster but still I don't understand what causes the problem. I attached a simple vector art that was rejected. It's so simple so I really cant see what a problem is in terms of raster, bitmaps.

[image]

Also the EPS can be found here, downgraded to Illustrator 8.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/gytc1xyajmmu55s/b13.jpg?dl=1

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: You uploaded a jpg to Dropbox, not the eps file.

Comment: if the attached jpg is what you sent to Shutterstock, there's your problem.

Comment: here is the link to eps https://www.dropbox.com/s/1f32b73ke7hsgpo/b13.eps?dl=1 , I know this is not a masterpiece but I used it to check shutterstocks requirements and general submission guidelines.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Your background is a raster image.

[image]

So remove that and you should be good to go!

Comment: It still looks poor quality, not good for stock image. What they called the bitmapping might be these corners on the curves. Make the curves smooth. These should be stroked path, not filled shapes., Expand before selling.

Comment: many thanks for the input...especially @Ovaryraptor thanks for the effort. I will compare it to my previous files and see it if works.

Comment: @Webster The "stock worthiness" aspect isn't relevant. Also, bitmapping couldn't be referring to the corners and being shapes is perfectly fine. You can't even make this shape with those angles with a single stroke.

Comment: Stock worthiness is in the question. I believe those shapes can be easily made with pen tool and tapered stroke.

Comment: Inless you mean to include the straight line corners. If you want a curve with corners it will take more work.

Comment: @Webster The question was technical not design based on why it was rejected. I'm pretty sure the shape is 100% intentional. IMO it looks very tiger claws to me.

Comment: Oh, I'm  sorry to both of you. I misunderstood the question. I thought those corners were mistakes. Maybe the editor at Shutterstock did also. If it's a clean shape saved correctly you can be sure its not rastered. Dodges are common in rejection letters.

Comment: @Ovaryraptor is definitely right. Im interested in the technical details why it was rejected. Before I dive into work to create a more complex and better work. I want to resolve all the common issues when submitting.

Comment: If the vector is approved...I will mark the answer as correct

Comment: @Ovyraptor, please [refrain doing free work](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) for others, even if it is easy and you enjoy it. It might attract other requests for free work and is [frowned upon in the SE community](https://graphicdesign.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3129/what-to-do-about-answers-to-requests-for-free-work).